# Hyphenated nodeName or DTD nested in XML causes Feeds XPath Parser failure

Tags: feeds, 8

I am using Feeds and [Feeds XPath Parser](https://drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser).

I have an XML source like this.

```
<xml>
  <records>
    <record>
      <EAC-CPF xmlns:eac="http://jefferson.village.virginia.edu/eac" xmlns:edit="http://nla.gov.au/nla.party" xml:id="_cb2bf3c2-b54c-42c3-a890-048c06549e45#10" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:isbn:1-931666-33-4 http://eac.staatsbibliothek-berlin.de/schema/cpf.xsd">
        <cpfDescription>
          <identity>...</identity>
        </cpfDescription>
      </EAC-CPF>
    </record>
  </records>
</xml>
```

Which I am trying to import with field settings like

```
EAC-CPF/cpfDescription/identity/...
```

With debugging turned on I can see that fields *outside* of the EAC-CPF node are correctly found whereas those within are not. I've tried various escaping of EAC-CPF but I'm wondering if its a limitation of XPath in PHP or the Parser module. Or is it the nested namespace and schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 errors regarding the xml:id and xsi:schemaLocation, but they are not fatal. I'm guessing the xsi namespace is defined previously.

There's nothing wrong with nested namespaces.

Is there a default namespace declare somewhere passed the root? That could be because of https://drupal.org/node/1220834.

The hyphen in EAC-CPF is not causing the problems.

Remember that if elements have a namepsace, the namespace must be present in the XPath query.

Comment: I've replaced the leading underscore in the xml:id which allows it to validate. I read about that somewhere, the first character. But the spec seems to think it is valid. xml:id follows the same rules as name which allow an underscore or a letter as the first character. So I'm confused.